# java applect OBJECT Tag

Tags: java, object, applet

We are now using the below tag to

```
<OBJECT classid = "clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" codebase = "https://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5_0_06-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,5,0,06" '
```

If the user doen't have java installed, a message will be prompted asking user for installing the java 1.5.

My two questions:

1. Is there anyway to ask the user for latest version to be installed? If so what should be given to the codebase?
2. We are planning to remove the codebase altogether, since it asking for java 1.5 (which is very old) to be intalled. Is there a way to display 
   **"Unable to load applet because of jvm not detected"**, in case user doesn't have java installed?

Comment: 1. I don't believe so.  There is no reason to require the latest version;  let Java's update scheduler (or Linux's software updater) worry about that.  You should require whatever minimum version is needed for your program to run.  2. You'd rather the browser *not* tell users how to get what they need to run your program?

Comment: That is **really** old information.  1) Due to recent security scares, Oracle updated the JRE such that it will ***always*** load the latest version of Java installed, irrespective of what was requested or specified. 2) The 'deployment toolkit script' was designed for that, but with Chrome not supporting applets at all, MS' new Windows 10 OS also includes a browser with no applet ability, and FF and Safari both blocking applets by default, recent tests suggests it.. does not work very well.